# Reflowable ePub TOC Links Not Working (all other internal links are)

Tags: adobe-indesign, epub

I am working on a reflowable ePub in InDesign, and the Table of Contents links are not working. When I view the ePub in iBooks and click Table of Contents in the top menu bar, they work fine. But the links on the page itself do not. They show up as links (blue with underline), but nothing happens when I click on them on the page.

They all link to text anchors. I have checked the Hyperlinks window, and when I check "Go to Destination" for each of the links, it goes to the right spot in the document. Yet when I export the reflowable epub, none of the TOC links work. I use internal links throughout the book, and they all work fine (except for TOC).

My method for creating the TOC was Layout > Table of Contents, and selecting "Section Titles" as the Paragraph Style pull.

Any thoughts or recommendations to try would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For internal links, you could try using [Cross-references](https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/cross-references.html) instead of Hyperlinks. You will need to delete the hyperlinks in order to insert a cross-reference to the text. Since the pages change constantly in an ePub (depending on font/size), this seems to be more accurate when in getting the links to go to the correct spot in your document.